# add an image as a placeholder when clicked it will bind and display the selected picture XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to display an icon as a placeholder  when I clicked it will capture a picture and change the icon for the stored picture  (capture a picture process is completed already . all I need is to trigger and display the results (picture file ) and replace the  placeholder (Add.png) icon for (capture file image )  using XAMARIN FORMS . any help ? thanks )

## XAML

```xml
<Image x:Name="Photo2" Source="Add.png" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnPhoto2_Clicked" />
    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

## XAML.CS

```cs
async void OnPhoto2_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    await App.Navigator.PushAsync(new TEST()); //when clicked navigate to a new page that store the gallery of images
}
```

Comment: What specific part are you having a problem with?

Comment: Can you tell or show me what type you are getting back from the photo process? Do you use the cross media plugin?